# Justice Tom Clark's concurrence, GIdeon v Wainwright - 1963 US

Tags: meaning-in-context, legalese

[Source:](http://caselaw.lp.findlaw.com/scripts/getcase.pl?navby=CASE&court=US&vol=372&page=335) *Gideon v Wainwright* (1963)

> I must conclude here, as in *Kinsella*, supra, that the Constitution makes no distinction between capital and noncapital cases. The Fourteenth Amendment requires due process of law for the deprival of "liberty" just as for deprival of "life," and there cannot constitutionally be a difference in the quality of the process based merely upon a supposed difference in the sanction involved.
>   ♦ How can the Fourteenth Amendment **tolerate a procedure which it condemns** in capital cases on the ground that ***deprival of liberty*** may be *less onerous* than ***deprival of life*** - a value judgment not universally accepted 3 - or that only `the latter deprival` is irrevocable? ♦
>   I can find no acceptable rationalization for such a result, and I therefore concur in the judgment of the Court.

Would someone please explain the meaning of Justice Tom Clark's entire rhetorical question (that I surrounded with diamonds)? For example, **tolerate** and **condemns** are antonyms.

Also, how does the italicised make sense? Does `the latter deprival` refer to the ***deprival of life***? But  ***deprival of life*** (ie death) is always irrevocable, so what's the problem or question here?

Yet ***deprival of liberty*** can be revocable (eg prisoners are deprived of many of their liberties, but this deprival is revoked upon their release back into society)? So one can validly argue that it's *less onerous*?

Comment: That is called a paradox. That is why the author is actually asking that same question: how **can** the amendment tolerate what it condemns? The author cannot find any rationalization for that, and I suspect any such rationalization would be in the realm of law rather than English anyway.

Comment: The amendment says that deprival of liberty and life both warrant the same treatment. If in capital cases, deprival of life is treated differently, the question is "how can that be?" That is the judge's question: how can the amendment say they are to be treated the same, and then treat them differently? The judge can think of two reasons: deprival of life is irrevocable, or deprival of life is a worse thing than deprival of liberty. The judge finds both arguments irrational, and upholds that the amendment should be read as both deprivals being treated the same.

Comment: Please note that I believe this question to be solely about law, and I will not put my comment in an answer. I'm trying to help you out, but I fail to see the _English_ side of things here...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about interpretation of law and not about the English language.

Comment: @oerkelens Thank you deeply. Please edit my post if necessary, but I'm trying to ask about the English here. Basically, I don't understand the meaning of the question between the diamonds. So I'm just trying to pose questions to illustrate my confusion.

Comment: You have perfectly worded the meaning of the question between diamonds! It means exactly what you think it means. However, you seem to struggle with the the legal part of it. The question means "how can a rule be A and B at the same time, when A and B are opposites?" That _is_ the question. The answer is: it is a **paradox**. As you said, it is a rhetorical question. The judge explains why such interpretation is nonsense, according to him.

Comment: This seems like a reading comprehension problem more than a language problem. The writing is complex, but I don't see a grammar or meaning misunderstanding that would make the passage clear if it was explained.

Comment: @oerkelens Thanks, but I'm confused by `You have perfectly worded the meaning of the question between diamonds! It means exactly what you think it means`. Where did I do this? I only asked questions in my OP? I'm still confused by that whole question between the diamonds, but I'll try to think more about the **paradox** in your comments (which I don't understand now).

Comment: You wrote "tolerate and condemns are antonyms". That is the essence of that question. The judge asks "How can this paint be black and white at the same time?". You now ask "what does that mean?" It means just that! "How is it possible that something has two opposing properties?" The judge uses this rhetorical question to introduce his opinion that such a thing is impossible, so one of the two properties are not really there. He goes on to explain that according to him, it should not be read as tolerating the described practice: reading it like that would mean it means two opposite things.

Comment: Imagine I would ask "You are telling me something impossible; how can a bird have no wings and still fly?", and you then open this question being all confused because I ask how a bird with no wings can fly. _I_ am asking that question, because I think it is impossible. The judge also thinks what he questions is _impossible_. That is why he disagrees with it.

Comment: @oerkelens Thank you effusively for your continual care. I think that I've understood more now, but will return to this later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... what's the problem or question here?

You have missed an important word: *only*.

> How can the Fourteenth Amendment tolerate a procedure which it
>   condemns in capital cases on the ground that deprival of liberty may
>   be less onerous than deprival of life - a value judgment not
>   universally accepted -- or that *only* the latter deprival is
>   irrevocable?

... on the ground ... that only the latter deprival (i.e. deprival of life) is irrevocable

That is, why should we not regard the deprival of liberty as irrevocable as well?

The passage does not say this, but: one can never recover the time during which one was not free.  A man who is wrongly convicted and then spends most of his adult life in prison has irrevocably lost those years during which he might have been engaged in the pursuit of happiness.

P.S. A paraphrase:

In matters relating to the deprival of liberty, how can we be expected to accept the view that the Fourteenth Amendment tolerates there a procedure which it condemns in matters relating to deprival of life? Those who would argue that we should accept that the Fourteenth Amendment distinguishes between life and liberty, tolerating for the one what it condemns for the other, are basing their arguments on an assumption that the deprival of liberty is less onerous (a value judgment not universally accepted) or on the assumption that the deprival of liberty is not irrevocable.

Comment: Interesting interpretation. I read it as the judge seeing the argument (that deprival of life is irrevocable, as opposed to deprival of liberty) but that whether the deprival is irrevocable or not is irrelevant, since the amendment deems both deprivals equally worthy of careful process. (Simply said, I read his argument as: the fact that you may be able to correct a mistake does not give you a priori the right to work carelessly.) Still more about law than English though...